# HTMLフォームのsetAttribute、removeAttributeが効きません

Tags: javascript, html, form

お世話になります。
HTMLおよびJavascriptで質問です。
以下のようなHTMLファイル、text.htmlを作成しました。

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <title>属性の変更テスト</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>属性の変更テスト</h1>
    <form method="get"
      action="https://test.example.com"
      name="TextForm">

      <input id="Text_1" type="text" name="Text_1" size=80 disabled /><br />
      <script>
    function makeTextEnabled() {
      document.getElementById('Text_1').removeAttribute("disabled");
      document.getElementById('Text_1').setAttribute("required");
    }
    function makeTextDisabled() {
      document.getElementById('Text_1').removeAttribute("required");
      document.getElementById('Text_1').setAttribute("disabled");
    }
      </script>

      <textarea cols="60" rows="2" onselect="makeTextEnabled()">
    このテキストを選択したらTextが有効になるはず
      </textarea><br />
      <textarea cols="60" rows="2" onselect="makeTextDisabled()">
    このテキストを選択したらTextが無効になるはず
      </textarea><br />

      <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Text_1というテキストボックスがあり、disabled属性で入力不能になっています。

scriptタグで2つの関数が定義されています。  
１つめのmakeTextEnabled()を呼ぶとText_1のdisable属性を無効にし、required属性を有効にしたいと思っています。  
２つめのmakeTextDisabled()を呼ぶとText_1のdisable属性を有効にし、required属性を無効ににしたいと思っています。

その下に2つのtextareaがあります。  
１つめの「このテキストを選択したらTextが有効になるはず」を選択すると、onselect()イベントが発火してmakeTextEnabled()が実行されるようにしたつもりです。  
２つめの「このテキストを選択したらTextが無効になるはず」を選択すると、やはりonselect()イベントでmakeTextDisabled()が実行されるようにしたつもりです。

現在のところは以下のとおりです。

- 初期状態では、Text_1は目論見通り無効になっています。  
  [image: 初期状態]
- １つめのテキストを選択すると、Text_1のdisableは外れましたが、requredはつきませんでした。  
  [image: １つめの関数は半分うまくいった]
- ２つめのテキストを選択すると、Text_1のdisableは復活しませんでした。requredはつきませんでした。  
  [image: ２つ目の関数は全然うまくいかなかった]

で、質問としては、  
1. １つめのテキストを選択してもrequiredがつかないのはなぜでしょうか？  
2. １つめのテキストを選択してもdisabledがつかないのはなぜでしょうか？

ブラウザーは必ずChromeです。  
どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setAttribute()`に第2引数を渡していないためです。

```
    function makeTextEnabled() {
      document.getElementById('Text_1').removeAttribute("disabled");
      document.getElementById('Text_1').setAttribute("required", true);
    }
    function makeTextDisabled() {
      document.getElementById('Text_1').removeAttribute("required");
      document.getElementById('Text_1').setAttribute("disabled", true);
    }
```

あるいはプロパティを使うという手もあります。

```
    function makeTextEnabled() {
      document.getElementById('Text_1').disabled = false;
      document.getElementById('Text_1').required = true;
    }
    function makeTextDisabled() {
      document.getElementById('Text_1').required = false;
      document.getElementById('Text_1').disabled = true;
    }
```

Comment: ありがとうございます！！！
バッチリ解決しました！！！